# how can i develop a blogging application in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to develop the blog application which is described in the book "ASP.NET MVC Framework Unleashed", the book is in asp.net mvc 1 , if i was to develop the same application using the razor engine and following the material in the same book, would i run into problems?

also is there any other material that is related to developing blogs using asp.net mvc?

Comment: A lot has changed in the MVC framework since version 1.  Since you want to use Razor, I assume you will be using MVC 3 or even MVC 4.  Trying to follow directions from a book about MVC 1 will probably be an exercise in frustration.  I would try one of the many tutorials out there designed for MVC 3, even if they're not about blogs.  Once you get a handle on the framework, developing a blog should be pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know that book... BUT here is some material regarding blog engine based on ASP.NET MVC:

- https://github.com/ChrisFulstow/NBlog
- http://www.funnelweblog.com/
- http://orchardproject.net/
- http://thebeerhouse.codeplex.com/
- http://oxite.codeplex.com/
- http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2205
- http://www.timacheson.com/Blog/2009/jun/creating_a_blog_from_scratch_with_asp.net_mvc
- http://www.arroyocode.com/a-file-based-blog-using-markdown-and-asp-net-mvc-3
- http://www.palmmedia.de/Blog/2011/2/7/aspnet-mvc-3-razor-based-blog-engine-with-sql-ce-40